# Trying to create Python code that inputs json and then displays it

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import json
import requests

def download_file(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)

api_url = 'https://api.fda.gov/download.json'
r = requests.get(api_url)
files = [file['file'] for file in json.loads(r.text)['results']['drug']['event']['partitions']]

count = 1
for file in files:
    download_file(file)
    print(f"{count}/{len(files)} downloaded!")
    count += 1
```

This is the other code

```
    import urllib.request, json 
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(data)
```

The first code just downloads it. I wondering if theres a way to not have to download any of the 1000+ files and just display it, so the code can be used locally. While the second one prints the json in the terminal.

Comment: You could just pre-download the contents of `api_url`, then save that to file and read it later.

Answer (score 0):

`requests.get()` and `urllib.request.urlopen()` both "download" the full response of the URL they are given.

If you do not want to "save" the file to disk, then remove the code that calls `f.write()`

More specifically,

```
import json
import requests

api_url = 'https://api.fda.gov/download.json'
r = requests.get(api_url)
files = [file['file'] for file in r.json()['results']['drug']['event']['partitions']]

total_files = len(files)

count = 0
for file in files:
    print(requests.get(file).content)
    print(f"{count+1}/{total_files} downloaded!")
    count += 1
```